# Is it possible to put a full installation of Windows 10 on a USB flash drive?

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, usb-flash-drive, external-drive

I have a laptop in which the internal drive bay has been destroyed, but the rest of the laptop works fine. I was wondering if it's possible to do a full installation of Windows 10 on a USB flash drive.

I'm aware of Windows To Go, but I'm not sure if it's what I want. I don't need a "portable" installation of Windows, I intend for the flash drive to be permanently connected to the computer. I would prefer for the system to function as normally as possible.

If I can't figure out how to do this, I'll probably just install Linux onto the flash drive instead.

Comment: This involve acquiring the Windows 10 ISO file and generating a bootable USB drive. Check this https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/install-windows-10-on-new-pc-without-os.html

Answer (score 3):

The official "Windows To Go" feature from Microsoft is only for Windows Enterprise
or Education and requires a certified USB flash drive (which are expensive).

The other alternative requires:

- The [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) freeware
- A Windows ISO

I describe below the procedure using Rufus.
An alternative product is
[FlashBoot](https://www.prime-expert.com/flashboot/),
that you may try if the installation as done by Rufus has problems.
A write-up of the process using FlashBoot can be found in the ghacks article
[How to create a running copy of Windows on USB Flash Drives](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/12/10/how-to-create-a-running-copy-of-windows-on-usb-flash-drives/).

Create and use the USB with Rufus as follows:

- In Rufus, select the USB device you want to install Windows on in the *Device* box
- Click *Select* and point at the Windows ISO to install
- Click on the "Image option" box and select "Windows To Go"
- Click "Partition Scheme" and select "MBR"
- Click "Target System" and select BIOS or UEFI.
- Click the "Start" button for Rufus to format the drive and install Windows
- Wait for the process to complete and then safely remove the USB drive from the PC
- Leave the USB connected to the computer
- Restart the computer and enter BIOS
- Set the PC to boot from the portable USB by changing the boot order
- Save BIOS changes and check that the boot from the USB does succeed

Notes:

- Starting with Windows version 1809 the USB needs to be formatted as type NTFS
  and not FAT32, since the file is larger than 4 GB
- Booting from "Windows To Go" or the Rufus-generated boot USB will require
  answering some dialogs, so is never as quick as from hard disk.

For more information see
[How (and Why) to Run Portable Versions of Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/406118/how-and-why-to-run-portable-versions-of-windows/).